# Две группы checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

Добрый день. Есть 2 группы чекбокс.

```
<input id="my_check" type="checkbox" name="color"/>
<label for="my_check">Space Gray</label>
<input id="my_checka" type="checkbox" name="color"/>
<label for="my_checka">Gold</label>
<input id="my_checkb" type="checkbox" name="color"/>
<label for="my_checkb">Dilver</label>
<input id="my_checkc" type="checkbox" name="color"/>
<label for="my_checkc">Pink</label>

<input id="gb" type="checkbox" name="gb"/>
<label for="gb">16 GB</label>
<input id="gb1" type="checkbox" name="gb"/>
<label for="gb1">64 GB</label>
<input id="gb2" type="checkbox" name="gb"/>
<label for="gb2">128 GB</label>
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы при выборе в первой группе 2 значений, все остальные в этой группе блокировались. Тоже самое для другой группы. 
У меня получился вот такой код:

```
<script>
var f = document.forms.Form;
f.onchange = function() {
  var n = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'),
      l = f.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  for(var j=0; j<n.length; j++)
    if (l.length >= 2) { // если отметить 2 и более галочки
      n[j].disabled = true; // все чекбоксы становятся disabled
      for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++)
        l[i].disabled = false; // но disabled убирается с помеченных галочками чекбоксов
    } else {
      n[j].disabled = false; // если выделить менее трёх галочек, то disabled снимается со всех чекбоксов
    }
}
</script>
```

Но он блокирует все чекбоксы во всех группах. Как сделать корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал для первой группы, для остальных думаю по аналогии догадаетесь как сделать.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("checkform"),
    colorcheck = form.getElementsByClassName("colorcheck"),
    memmorycheck = form.getElementsByClassName("memmorycheck");

for(var i = 0; i < colorcheck.length; i++) {
 colorcheck[i].onchange = function() {
        var count = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < colorcheck.length; i++) 
            if(colorcheck[i].checked) count++;
        
        if(count > 1){
            for(var i = 0; i < colorcheck.length; i++){   
                if(!colorcheck[i].checked) {
                    colorcheck[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(var i = 0; i < colorcheck.length; i++) {
                colorcheck[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="checkform">
    <input id="my_check" type="checkbox" name="color" class="colorcheck"/>
    <label for="my_check">Space Gray</label>
    <input id="my_checka" type="checkbox" name="color" class="colorcheck"/>
    <label for="my_checka">Gold</label>
    <input id="my_checkb" type="checkbox" name="color" class="colorcheck"/>
    <label for="my_checkb">Dilver</label>
    <input id="my_checkc" type="checkbox" name="color" class="colorcheck"/>
    <label for="my_checkc">Pink</label>
    <br />
    <input id="gb" type="checkbox" name="gb" class="memmorycheck"/>
    <label for="gb">16 GB</label>
    <input id="gb1" type="checkbox" name="gb" class="memmorycheck"/>
    <label for="gb1">64 GB</label>
    <input id="gb2" type="checkbox" name="gb" class="memmorycheck"/>
    <label for="gb2">128 GB</label>
</form>
```